# How do I create a code first model that references another model twice in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to understand how to do this with a code first method.  I understand how to do it way back when I used to do more code with a SQL statement and ASP.  Now I'm trying to teach myself how to understand it with a code first MVC method in C#.

To start with, I'm looking to reproduce something like this, if I was to explain what I want in SQL.

```
    Select s1.systemname, s2.systemname, j,jumplaneid 
    from systems s1, systems s2, jumplanes j 
    where s1.systemid = j.system1id and s2.systemid = j.system2id
```

Here is the model I have for the systems.

```
    public class system
    {
    public virtual int systemid { get; set; }
    public virtual string systemname { get; set; }
    public virtual int? posx { get; set; }
    public virtual int? posy { get; set; }
    public virtual int? starluminosityid { get; set; }
    public virtual int? stellartypeid { get; set; }
    public virtual int? starspectralclassid { get; set; }
    public virtual int? carry { get; set; }
    public virtual int? raw { get; set; }
    public virtual int? bio { get; set; }
    public virtual int? jumppoints { get; set; }
    public virtual int? specialrolls { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<settlement> settlements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<fleet> fleets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Jumplane> jumplanes { get; set; }
    public virtual stellartype Stellartype { get; set; }
    public virtual starluminosity Luminosity { get; set; }
    public virtual starspectralclass SpectralClass { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create a jumplane model that would reference the system model for endpoints.  I set it up like this, which I think is close, but not quite there. Thoughts?

```
public class Jumplane
{
    public virtual int jumplaneid { get; set; }
    public virtual int jumpcost { get; set; }
    public virtual string jumplanename { get; set; }
    public virtual system system1 { get; set; }
    public virtual system system2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Supplyline> supplylines { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute the "update-database" to get everything to set up in the database, I get a trace that looks like this:

```
    PM> update-database -force
    Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
    No pending code-based migrations.
    Applying automatic migration: 201302030335260_AutomaticMigration.
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is     ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
    ClientConnectionId:c4c1ba62-806b-4e68-bb0b-161da4d9e23e
    Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
```

I understand how to do it, if I set up the database first, but I'm trying to learn the code first method.  Anybody more versed with more current trends in software development able to give me a steer?

Thanks!

***Updated:  Thank you to both of you, learned something from each of you.***

Here is where I ended up.

```
    public class Jumplane
{
    [Key]
    public int jumplaneid { get; set; }      
    [Range (1,1000)]
    public decimal jumpcost { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string jumplanename { get; set; }
    public virtual Starsystem starsystem1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Starsystem starsystem2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Supplyline> supplylines { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Starsystem
{
    [Key]
    public int starsystemid { get; set; }
    public string systemname { get; set; }
    public int? posx { get; set; }
    public int? posy { get; set; }
    public int? starluminosityid { get; set; }
    public int? stellartypeid { get; set; }
    public int? starspectralclassid { get; set; }
    public int? carry { get; set; }
    public int? raw { get; set; }
    public int? bio { get; set; }
    public int? jumppoints { get; set; }
    public int? specialrolls { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<settlement> settlements { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<fleet> fleets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Jumplane> jumplanes { get; set; }
    public virtual stellartype Stellartype { get; set; }
    public virtual starluminosity Luminosity { get; set; }
    public virtual starspectralclass SpectralClass { get; set; }
}
```

I am going to back and catch the additional annotations.  Because my head has gone and gotten all covered in pointy hair, I missed the significance of the annotations.

The issue I had with the Update-Database became clear when you suggested it was a rename issue.  Adding the -Verbose option made that very clear to me.  I probably cheated, but I simplified the model by removing both of the starsystem references in it, updated the database and then added them back one by one.

I also appreciate the code review on class capitalization and use of the "virtual" keyword.  I did leave the more descriptive prefix on id and name, but that is mostly for me as I'm likely to get confused later if I leave them off.  Since the code is just for me, I decided to pass on that particular piece of advice, but the feedback was (and is) still most welcome.

Thank you both again for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually spawns when you are trying to rename table.

I have a suggestion for you to create your Model and try to achieve your desired results with minimal possible fields. Also, you want to use `virtual` keyword only on foreign entities.

I've just tested something similar (Admin, AdminLog[Contains Admin1 and Admin2]) and it worked just fine.

### Code you should try

```
public class System
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Jumplane
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual System System1 { get; set; }
    public virtual System System2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now that this code will work and you will be able to execute your desired LINQ query just add all other fields to it.

Some pointers (maybe subjective)

- Virtual for foreign only
- Classes start with capital letter
- No need for `SystemID`, `SystemName` fields, just `ID` and `Name` will do since you will see that it belongs to `System`

Answer (score 0):

A query like the one you want in EF, would be something like `dbContext.Jumplanes.Include("system1").Include("system2")`

Having said that, your model has no attribute/annotations and everything is virtual. You only need to set a property to be virtual when you want it to be loaded lazily. A primary key of an element should not really be loaded lazily.

Take a look at `Key` and `ForeignKey` attributes, annotate your model with those, remove the virtual keywords where not needed and then let us know how it went :)